# How to translate "outside" into Russian language?

Tags: словоупотребление

I found some words in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-russian/outside_1) but it is not clear to me when to use each one of them and how:

```
снаружи, вне, за пределами, под
```

Now I have some examples:

- There is no students **outside** the class (car, bus, metro).
- It is in the box or **outside** the box.
- Wait me please **outside** the room, I will call you when your turn comes.

Comment: No straightforward translation. While "Снаружи", "За пределами", "Вне" are satisfactory translations, in real contexts different, more specific words will usually be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> There are no students outside the class - Вне класса / Снаружи студентов нет
>
> It is in the box or outside the box - Это в коробке или вне коробки
>
> Please wait outside the room - Подожди, пожалуйста, за пределами/вне комнаты / снаружи

**За пределами** is mainly used with objects denoting large spaces and which have formal boundaries. It's a more technical preposition.

**Снаружи** normally doesn't require an object, i.e. used by itself, the object is implied being derived from the context.

Out of the three **cнаружи** and **вне** are the most usable in mundane speech.

**Под** is synonymous with the other three in the context of relative disposition of cities and suburbs when cities proper names are mentioned.

> Мы живём **под** Москвой - We live **outside** Moscow
>
> *But*
>
> We live **outside** the city - Мы живём **за** городом

**Под** also can be translated as **outside** in the sense of **in front of / near** a building, e.g.

> Встречаемся **под** университетом <sup>*colloquial, poss. regional*</sup>- Let's meet up **outside** of the university

Otherwise it literally means **under(neath)**.

Comment: The usage of под ("under") in relation to being outside (not literally under) a city is similar to the English word suburb, whose Latin etymology (sub + urbs) looks like "under city", although in that usage sub means "near".

Comment: "Встречаемся под университетом" - that sounds really odd, like they are going to university's basement.

Comment: @Alexander how about **встречаемся под магазином** or **я час прождал его под домом**, оr **я стоял под дверью, но она всё равно не открывала**, or the classic **три девицы под окном пряли поздно вечерком**, or **у меня под окном растёт вишня**? anyway this is one of the way preposition **под** is used in my area, but useful to know that this may not be typical to other places

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка - "под дверью" and "под окном" are well established. However, "под магазином" I have never heard in my life (if referring to a specific, rather than deliberately vague location near a landmark). "У магазина" is traditionally used instead.

Comment: @Alexander here're a few examples from [Google](http://goo.gl/zvCEm6) of the phrase **под кинотеатром** combined with the verb **стоять** and occasionally some others dispersed among conventional phrases

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка imho this search results demonstrate that "стоять" and "под кинотеатром" do not go along very well :) Also, all the results that I checked refer to the _vicinity_ of a cinema theater rather than a specific location.

Comment: @Alexander i just showed that such use does exist, not sure what you mean by specific location, but usually *под + building* as a place of meeting means in the area around the main entrance, where it's easier to spot a person, this is logical

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка - sorry, not in the link that you have provided. None of the first page examples shows "под кинотеатром" as a _proposed_ meeting place, just one refers to a person standing "под кинотеатром", and many examples refer to something _underneath_ the building.

Comment: @Alexander i didn't claim it was in the search results or followed from them, because as i wrote they pertained to **стоять + под кинотеатром**, not exactly a connotation of meeting per se, so it was my own explanation and i don't see big semantic difference between **встречаться под зданием** and **стоять под зданием**

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка my point is that choosing a meeting place "под зданием" is virtually unheard of in Russian language. If someone proposes it to me, I would assume that the building has an underground level, and ask for clarification. At the same time, places "под фонарем", "под памятником" and "под часами" are usable.

Comment: @Alexander indeed, someone who's unfamiliar with such use, which could be mainly a Ukrainian regionalism (e.g. [**собираться под магазином**](http://goo.gl/RAFhrL)), might require clarification

Comment: I've even **never heard** anything like "под университетом", it made me wonder, maybe it was about an underground parking lot or informally about meeting at the bottom of the stairs (with the particular university high on a hill). I'd only accept _под часами, под мостом or под аркой._

Comment: @Alex_ander no, as i explained and exemplified with references above, it means *near the building*, and i guess it's not hard to fathom, because buildings tower above people so if feels like you're being thereunder

Comment: @Alex_ander Под университетом, под магазином - This sounds completely fine to me and I speak often so. May be this depends on region

Comment: @demonplus this is probably because according to your profile info you're from Ростов-на-Дону as there's greater cultural and lingusitc affinity between this region of Russia and Ukraine

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Agree, this should be region specific.

Answer (score 4):

The literal word for outside is **снаружи**, however its usage is mainly limited to something like **boxes** or **containers**. It doesn't combine well with rooms and buildings, so proper translation in those two cases depends much on context:

> outside (the room) - **в коридоре, за дверью** (the latter is not polite
> in a request to wait there);
>
> outside (the building) - **на улице, у входа (в здание), у подъезда**
>
> It's raining outside. - **На улице дождь.**

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned they are mostly the same (though `под` also means "under"), the exact usage depends on the finesse. Here, I am trying to capture it in translation.

- `Снаружи` is outside in the sense of "there is also *inside* and it's not it". Like, outside the box.
- `Вне` is outside in the sense of "no bounds". It's also a bit oldish and bookish. (For example, there was a classic short Sci-Fi story from the Golded Era called "Извне", which basically means "from ouside", the antonym of "within", but conveys the meaning of "from outer space".)

  `Вне` is also more abstract. "Outside the building" is `снаружи`, "any categories do not apply here" is `вне категорий`.
- `За пределами` is verbatim "out of bounds". There should be some boundary for it, like "outside the city".
- I at first translated `под` as "under". Indeed, there is also a somewhat colloquial meaning "closeby", as in `под окном`: "I'll be waiting outside in front of your window." Other answers elaborate a bit on this, somehow in the usage it's always outside the building/object that is referenced.